# Working with base10 values in Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

Cloud Datastore does not support Decimal values, only floats, so how do I save and load base10 values like 1.23 ?

I have thought about storing as Int and saving 1.23 as 123, which would work I suppose, with some simple math to move the dot, but is that really the way to go? It seems tedious to be doing this kind of conversion all the time, just to save and load the exact base10 value.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I may not understand the problem well. What is your input type? If string can you just save it as string? And only convert and do correct math when you need to...

Comment: Yes, that is the way to do it.  I don't know anything about Go, but maybe you can make your own Class to make the conversion less tedious.